# Why second ifelse not evaluated in R and why if else does not vectorize?

Tags: r, if-statement, sapply

Consider the following `df`:

```
structure(list(GID7173723 = c("A", "T", "G", "A", "G"), GID4878677 = c("G", 
"C", "G", "A", "G"), GID88208 = c("A", "T", "G", "A", "G"), GID346403 = c("A", 
"T", "G", "A", "G"), GID268825 = c("G", "C", "G", "A", "G")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is how it looks:

```
  GID7173723 GID4878677 GID88208 GID346403 GID268825
1          A          G        A         A         G
2          T          C        T         T         C
3          G          G        G         G         G
4          A          A        A         A         A
5          G          G        G         G         G
```

Now consider two vectors:

```
ref <- c("A", "T", "G", "A", "G")
alt <- c("G", "C", "T", "C", "A")
```

And the function:

```
f = function(x){
  ifelse(x==ref,2,x)
  ifelse(x==alt,0,x)
}
```

When I run `sapply` just the second `ifelse` evaluates:

`sapply(dfn,f)`

```
     GID7173723 GID4878677 GID88208 GID346403 GID268825
[1,] "A"        "0"        "A"      "A"       "0"      
[2,] "T"        "0"        "T"      "T"       "0"      
[3,] "G"        "G"        "G"      "G"       "G"      
[4,] "A"        "A"        "A"      "A"       "A"      
[5,] "G"        "G"        "G"      "G"       "G"
```

If I run something like that:

```
f = function(x){
  if (x==ref) {return(2)
    
  }
  else if (x==alt) {return(0)
    
  }
  else {
    return(x)
  }
}
```

I get the warning message:

`sapply(dfn,f)`

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == ref) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == ref) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (x == alt) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (x == ref) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (x == ref) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (x == ref) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (x == alt) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I believe the latter function is due to the nature of `if else` to not vectorize. I really would like to solve this problem without using neither `for` loops nor `sweep` but only with `if else` statements followed by the `apply` family functions.

Comment: Can you please provide your expected final output?

Comment: To answer to the question on the header: `ifelse` is vetcorized, but `if` is not. That's why you get that warning: `condition has length > 1`. `if` is expecting a length 1 logical vector.

Answer (score 2):

You may try making an assignment with the first call to `ifelse`:

```
f <- function(x){
    x <- ifelse(x == ref, 2, x)
    return(ifelse(x == alt, 0, x))
}
```

The main problem with your current approach is that the first `ifelse` is not "sticking" without an assignment on the LHS.

Comment: LHS ? what that means ?

Comment: LHS = left hand side of the expression, with your first `ifelse` being the RHS

Comment: you could shorten this to `ifelse(x ==ref,2,ifelse(x==alt, 0 ,x))`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes we could...I guess it is a matter of code readability versus conciseness.

Answer (score 1):

- When you are comparing values with a vector use `%in%` and not `==` because `==` does an element-wise comparison.
- You need to save the changes of first `ifelse` statement before executing second statement.

Change your function to :

```
f = function(x){
   x <- ifelse(x %in% ref,2,x)
   x  <- ifelse(x %in% alt,0,x)
   return(x)
}
```

You can then use `lapply` :

```
dfn[] <- lapply(dfn,f)
```

Comment: what I want is an element-wise comparison so I believe `==` is correct. That is the first element of the `vector` compared to each element in the `df` column.

Comment: That is not what is happening when you use `==`. :)

Comment: but I'm having the result which I expect with `==` element-wise comparisons of the `vector` along the columns of `df`. Since the `vector` has the same `length` of the columns of `df` no recycling occurs which is what i want.

Comment: OP is correct by claiming elementwise comparison using `==` it is not correct to use `%in%`

Comment: @Onyambu what do you mean by OP ? Sorry

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini you are the OP in this case, ie Original Poster(OP) Of the thread